# ShortHand for loop with list operation

Tags: python-3.x

How can I write this in shorthand notion:

```
bigger_list=[]
for item in items:
    new_list = item.nested_items
    bigger_list += new_list
```

I have tried this, but it is not working

```
bigger_list += [item.nested_items for item in items]
```

Comment: Are you extending bigger_list by a smaller `list` or by a single item? What is the `type` of `item.nest_items`?

Answer (score 3):

```
bigger_list = [i.nested_item for i in items]
```

Comment: Given that `i.nested_items` suggests a type of `list`, I believe this answer produces a `list` of `list`s rather than `extend`ing a single `bigger_list` of items.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are attempting to make a single "merged" `bigger_list` out of many smaller `nested_items` lists (iterables). I believe you are looking to do:

```
bigger_list=[]
for item in items:
    bigger_list.extend(item.nested_items)
```

There might be some temptation to try this via a comprehension as they tend to short and sweat:

```
bigger_list=[]
foo = [bigger_list.extend(item.nested_items) for item in items]
```

but comprehensions are for creating lists, not extending them. Don't use a comprehension like this. See : [Is it Pythonic to use list comprehensions for just side effects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753597/is-it-pythonic-to-use-list-comprehensions-for-just-side-effects)

**If you were still very keen on using a comprehension, you could do the following but I think it is nowhere near as easy to follow as the simple `for`:**

```
bigger_list = [nested_item for item in items for nested_item in item.nested_items]
```

If the intension is that `bigger_list` is to be a list of lists or that `nested_items` is not an iterable, then the answer by @rishin is what you want.